# .tbl file import request for a .tlh file C++

Tags: visual-c++, import, tbl

I'm working in a C++ native project and I need to import a .tbl file

```
#import  "C:\packages\S...\xx.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, named_guids, no_namespace
```

But Visual studio 2019 always ask for a .tlh file that I don't have, how can I use tbl file without the tlh file?

Comment: The [`import` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=msvc-160) (which is specific to Visual Studio) [*creates*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=msvc-160#_predir_the_23import_directive_header_files_created_by_import) the header. No idea why your IDE then fails to locate it.

Comment: "*always ask for a .tlh file*" Please quote the *exact* error message.